# kedro error: Pipeline does not contain nodes named ['preprocess_companies']

Tags: python, nodes, pipeline, kedro

I was following the kedro pipelines tutorial[1](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/03_tutorial/04_create_pipelines.html), create all needed files, started the kedro with
kedro run --node=preprocess_companies

It returns the following error ValueError: Pipeline does not contain nodes named ['preprocess_companies']. did try to find solution but did not manage. Thank you for helping!

I use the following files 3:

1)
C:\Users\Name\tutorrr\src\tutorrr\pipelines\data_engineering\nodes.py

```
**import pandas as pd
def _is_true(x):
    return x == "t"
def _parse_percentage(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return float(x.replace("%", "")) / 100
    return float("NaN")
def _parse_money(x):
    return float(x.replace("$", "").replace(",", ""))
def preprocess_companies(companies: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Preprocess the data for companies.
        Args:
            companies: Source data.
        Returns:
            Preprocessed data.
    """
    companies["iata_approved"] = companies["iata_approved"].apply(_is_true)
    companies["company_rating"] = companies["company_rating"].apply(_parse_percentage)
    return companies
def preprocess_shuttles(shuttles: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Preprocess the data for shuttles.
        Args:
            shuttles: Source data.
        Returns:
            Preprocessed data.
    """
    shuttles["d_check_complete"] = shuttles["d_check_complete"].apply(_is_true)
    shuttles["moon_clearance_complete"] = shuttles["moon_clearance_complete"].apply(
        _is_true
    )
    shuttles["price"] = shuttles["price"].apply(_parse_money)
    return shuttles**
```

2
C:\Users\Name\tutorrr\src\tutorrr.pipeline.py

```
**from typing import Dict
from kedro.pipeline import Pipeline
from src.tutorrr.pipelines.data_engineering import pipeline as de
def create_pipelines(**kwargs) -> Dict[str, Pipeline]:
    """Create the project's pipeline.
    Args:
        kwargs: Ignore any additional arguments added in the future.
    Returns:
        A mapping from a pipeline name to a ``Pipeline`` object.
    """
    de_pipeline = de.create_pipeline()
    return {
        "de": de_pipeline,
        "__default__": de_pipeline,
    }**
```

3)C:\Users\Name\tutorrr\src\tutorrr\pipelines\data_engineering\pipeline.py

```
**from kedro.pipeline import node, Pipeline
from src.tutorrr.pipelines.data_engineering.nodes import (
    preprocess_companies,
    preprocess_shuttles,
)
def create_pipeline(**kwargs):
    return Pipeline(
        [
            node(
                func=preprocess_companies,
                inputs="companies",
                outputs="preprocessed_companies",
                name="preprocessing_companies",
            ),
            node(
                func=preprocess_shuttles,
                inputs="shuttles",
                outputs="preprocessed_shuttles",
                name="preprocessing_shuttles",
            ),
        ]
    )**
```

And this is what I receive:

```
new_env) C:\Users\Name\tutorrr>kedro run --node=preprocess_companies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\kedro\cli\cli.py", line 594, in load_entry_points
    entry_point_commands.append(entry_point.load())
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2472, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (python-dateutil 2.8.1 (c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('python-dateutil==2.8.0'))
Error: Loading global commands from kedro-viz = kedro_viz.server:commands
2020-05-07 11:30:15,999 - root - INFO - ** Kedro project tutorrr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\Scripts\kedro.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\kedro\cli\cli.py", line 638, in main
    ("Project specific commands", project_groups),
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\tutorrr\kedro_cli.py", line 278, in run
    pipeline_name=pipeline,
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\kedro\context\context.py", line 459, in run
    from_inputs=from_inputs,
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\kedro\context\context.py", line 375, in _filter_pipeline
    new_pipeline &= pipeline.only_nodes(*node_names)
  File "c:\users\Name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda4\envs\new_env\lib\site-packages\kedro\pipeline\pipeline.py", line 460, in only_nodes
    list(unregistered_nodes)
ValueError: Pipeline does not contain nodes named ['preprocess_companies'].
```

Answer (score 2):

You named the node "preprocessing_companies" not "preprocess_companies".

So 'kedro run --node=preprocessing_companies' should work. You can also find the tutorial example code in https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro-examples